# Scripting a sequential workflow in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, script, applescript

I currently have a workflow which relies on several bash commands sequentially in the OSX terminal. It is basically a process which starts with a file `x.csv`, it does an operation on it and generates another file `y.dat`. Then uses `y.dat` as input for another command line app and produces the output `z.png`.

I want to write a script to automate the procedure with a script that takes in `x` and produces `z` directly. I don't know how to do it, or if to use AppleScript or bash and how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use a pipe i.e. `|` to pass the output of one command as the input of the next.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html

Answer (score -1):

I used the tutorial in http://floppix.ccai.com/scripts1.html to get started. That is all I needed. I execute a command and use a variable to store the filename of the output. I then execute the next command passing the filename of the previous stage as a parameter.

Comment: Please expand your answer and explain what exactly you did. Having  a link is nice but it doesn't really tell us how you solved your problem.

Comment: You are just linking to a short cookbook for a simple script (which does not contain any hint about how to pipe data from one process to the other)

Comment: I added some more detail. Basically I'm just using intermediate files instead of passing the output directly onto the next command.